# I can't access my php ini file

Tags: php, configuration

I can't see my php.ini  file. There is a no path located in my phpinfo() function.. I am using mac. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: `/etc/php.ini` is where your mac'd be looking. if it doesn't exist, then php will simply use its compiled-in default settings. the .ini files are there simply to OVERRIDE those defaults.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, but how can I change my configuration file path? There is nothing in that file.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php   that's a list of all the options you can put into a .ini file